# Foldr in scheme

Tags: scheme

I'm learning accumulation and foldr but something in my code is wrong. I'd like compare elements in all the list but foldr use only first and second element. Here is my code:

```
(define accum?
  (lambda (list1 pre?)
  (foldr (lambda (x y) 
               (if (pre? (car list1) (cadr list1)) #t #f))
         #f
         list1)))

(accum? '(1 2 3 4) <) --> #t
(accum? '(3 2 3 4) <) --> #f
(accum? '(1 2 5 4) <) --> #t (should be #f)
(accum? '(5 7 2 3) <) --> #t (should be #f)
```

Do you have any idea where is a mistake? By the way, it is better to use only (pre? (car list1) (cadr list1)) without if --> (if <...> #t #f)?

Comment: Yes, it's better to use `pre?` directly, notice that the `if` ends up returning the same as `pre?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be solved a lot easier with `apply`, using the fact that the comparison operators receive a variable number of arguments:

```
(apply < '(1 2 3 4))
=> #t

(apply < '(1 2 5 4))
=> #f
```

**UPDATE**

For this problem in particular, `foldr` is not the right tool for the job (although it's not impossible, as you've [demonstrated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670780/need-t-but-get-first-element-scheme)) - there isn't a value to be "accumulated" while the list is being traversed, the list is either ordered or not for the given predicate.

From the comments, I understand that the `pre?` procedure can be an arbitrary `lambda` that receives exactly two parameters.

A possible solution would be to create al list of all pairs of consecutive elements, and check if the predicate holds true for all of them. Notice that the last element won't have a corresponding pair, so we need to exclude it from the list of pairs. For that, I'll define a special `zip` procedure that, given two input lists, takes care of creating a list of pairs taking into account the fact that the lists can be of different lengths:

```
(define (zip lst1 lst2)
  (if (or (null? lst1) (null? lst2))
      '()
      (cons (list (car lst1) (car lst2))
            (zip (cdr lst1) (cdr lst2)))))

(zip '(1 2 3) '(2 3))
=> '((1 2) (2 3))
```

Now putting all together, we can solve the original problem like this:

```
(define (accum? lst pre?)
  (andmap (lambda (tuple)
            (pre? (car tuple) (cadr tuple)))
          (zip lst (cdr lst))))
```

Bear in mind that it won't work for empty lists, but it's trivial to add a special case for this. Now the comparison can be made with arbitrary `lambdas`:

```
(accum? '(1 2 3) (lambda (a b) (= a (- b 1))))
=> #t
```

Comment: I know about apply. Problem is, it doesn't work with this: (accum? '(1 3 4) (lambda (a b) (= a (- b 1)))) because predicate isn't standard. It can be some lambda expression.

Comment: @Ats `apply` can work with any procedure, as long as the correct number of parameters are passed. The code in my answer works because for comparison operators, the "correct number of parameters" is anything greater than or equal to zero. On the other hand, and I was about to update my answer, you won't find a straightforward way to solve this problem with `foldr`, is just not the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

It's only using the first and second element because you explicitly use `(car list1)` and `(cadr list1)`, which get the first and second element.

Note that when you're not actually using `x` and `y`, the arguments passed to the lambda. This is a sure sign you're doing something wrong.

PS: This is unrelated to your problem, but writing `(if condition #t #f)` is pretty much the same thing as just writing `condition`. So yes, leaving out the `if` is better as it serves no purpose.

Comment: I see, (pre? x y). But now is this problem: <: expects type <real number> as 2nd argument, given: #t; other arguments were: 4.

Comment: @Ats Yes, that's because the way you've written it, the second argument to the `lambda` will be a boolean, but `<` expects two numbers as arguments. I'm not sure you want to be using `foldr` for this at all. And if you do, you need to pass more than a simple boolean around as the accumulator.

Comment: I need to use foldr. I'm trying check empty list for last argument but I don't know how.