# Need #t but get first element (Scheme)

Tags: scheme

I think I have almost done solution with previous problem: [Foldr in scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661367/foldr-in-scheme) but in code is a small trouble. I need #t but I get first element, false is OK. Here is my code:

```
(define accum
  (lambda (list1 pre?)
    (foldr (lambda (x y)
             (if y
                 (if (or (equal? y #t) (pre? x y))
                     x
                     #f)
                 #f))
           #t
           list1)))

(accum '(1 2 3 4) <=) --> 1 (should be #t)
(accum '(2 2 4 4) <=) --> 2 (should be #t)
(accum '(1 2 5 4) <=) --> #f
(accum '(5 7 2 3) <=) --> #f
```

If I write "x --> #t", I always get #t, even if is #f.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can always wrap the result with another procedure that returns the correct type:

```
(define (accum? list1 pre?)
  (if (accum list1 pre?) #t #f))
```

Comment: @Ats you're welcome! that was quite a brain teaser you had to solve there, great job! :) . I understand it was a homework assignment and your solution is perfect, but bear in mind that in real-life `foldr` might not be the best option for solving this problem - it keeps iterating over _all_ the elements, even after finding out that the condition isn't true for some elements

Comment: An additional exercise for the reader: what happens if the given list holds booleans (and the `pre?` expects to get those booleans)?

E.g., what is supposed to happen in cases like this:

    `(define (bool< x y) (or x (not y)))`

    `(accum (list #t #f #f) bool<)`
    `(accum (list #f #f #f) bool<)`

(And what will the code listed above in the question do in this case?)